# Python 2.7 AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm using BeautifulSoup and urllib to make a Wikipedia web scraper. I just keep getting the same annoying error.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

page = urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
nickname = soup.find_all("span", class_="nickname")
nickname.replace('[<span class="nickname">','')
nickname.replace('</span>]','')
print(nickname)
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: nickname is not a string

Comment: @user1767754 That's seems to help a little. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nickname` has datatype `ResultSet`, you have to convert it to a string if you want to do some string operations on it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

page = urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
nickname = soup.find_all("span", class_="nickname")
nicknameStr = str(nickname)
nicknameStr.replace('[<span class="nickname">','')
nicknameStr.replace('</span>]','')
print(nicknameStr)
```